# Найти второй пробел

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

Как найти *второй пробел* в строке?

```
let str = 'exit test some';
let value;
value = str.indexOf(' ');
```

Comment: Почитайте про второй параметр indexOf в документации.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Очень хороший [справочник.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Как видим, второй параметр есть:

> Необязательный параметр. Местоположение внутри строки, откуда начинать
>   поиск. Может быть любым целым числом. Значение по умолчанию
>   установлено в 0. Если `fromIndex < 0`, поиск ведётся по всей строке (так
>   же, как если бы был передан 0). Если `fromIndex >= str.length`, метод
>   вернёт -1, но только в том случае, если `searchValue` не равен пустой
>   строке, в этом случае он вернёт `str.length`.

```js
var str = 'Hello world! Hi!';

// Здесь находим позицию пробела начиная от позиции первого пробела
var position = str.indexOf(' ', str.indexOf(' ') + 1);
console.log(position);
```